# How to reload a view after router.navigate in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I have a switch to shop function which is controlled by a header component and displays a dashboard for that venue.

In that header component, I navigate to dashboard route, even if I already in that route.

```
this.router.navigate(['/venues', this.currentVenue._id, 'dashboard']);
```

But it doesn't trigger ngOnInit hook again so my view is not reloaded.

What is the correct workaround for such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to reload the view? Or just reget some data?

If you only need to reget data based on the routing parameter, you can do this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        params => {
            const id = +params['id'];
            this.getMovie(id);   // <- Or whatever you need to do here
        }
    );
}
```

In the ngOnInit, this code subscribes to the route parameters. So every time the parameters change, even if the view is not changed/reloaded, the change will be picked up as part of the subscription and the associated callback is executed.